# ERROR: error when installing POintnet++, how to solve it?

Tags: point-cloud-library

'(PVN3D-pytorch) PS D:\PVN3D-pytorch-1.5\PVN3D-pytorch-1.5\Pointnet2_PyTorch> pip install -r requirements.txt

```
    File "C:\Users\666\anaconda3\envs\PVN3D-pytorch\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\_vendor\packaging\version.py", line 196, in __init__
      match = self._regex.search(version)
  TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pointnet2-ops
Running setup.py clean for pointnet2-ops
Failed to build pointnet2-ops
Installing collected packages: pointnet2-ops, markdown, hydra-core, google-auth, google-auth-oauthlib, tensorboard, pytorch-lightning
Running setup.py install for pointnet2-ops ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Running setup.py install for pointnet2-ops did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [106 lines of output]
No CUDA runtime is found, using CUDA_HOME='C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.1'
running install
C:\Users\666\anaconda3\envs\PVN3D-pytorch\lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\cmd.py:66: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated.
!!

```
          ********************************************************************************
          Please avoid running ``setup.py`` directly.
          Instead, use pypa/build, pypa/installer or other
          standards-based tools.

          See https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html for details.
          ********************************************************************************

  !!
    self.initialize_options()
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37

  copying pointnet2_ops\_ext-src\include\ball_query.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-
    File "C:\Users\666\anaconda3\envs\PVN3D-pytorch\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\_vendor\packaging\version.py", line 196, in __init__
      match = self._regex.search(version)
  TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pointnet2-ops
note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.'